# Creating glass material - Glass shader or Principled give black/dark or mirror render in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders, glass

I have already searched for as many threads I could find to find a solution and tried them all as best as I could, but I can't make glass shader or Principled shader work with to make a transparent material resembling a realistic glass or clear acrylic. It almost always shows as completely black, or sometimes mirror-like

The most common solution to this was to increase bounce values, which I have done. I have also tried flipping and recalculating faces and tried different lights. The only closest material I can make to a glass is by using a transparent shader with a glossy one, but its result isn't satisfactory. The environment is set to black background, and setting it to any other colour just introduces reflection of that colour on upper half of the sphere.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is very hard to tell what is going on here by just looking at the screenshots. Please share the .blend-file.

Comment: The only way I can replicate this behaviour is by adjusting the properties of your *floor* to only be visible to the camera - so it's not interacting with the glass. This way only the world background is affecting the 'glass' and so it apears to simply be reflecting the background (but it's actually reflecting and refracting the background).

Answer (score 3):

Idk if this is the result you're looking for but this is the material I use.

[image]

Comment: It has more reflection and refraction than transparency for what I want, but more importantly the rendered result still shows completely black. But the rendered view is similar to your rendered view : https://i.imgur.com/jjArfue.jpg

Does anyone have any idea what would be the cause of it?

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was "AO Bounce" setting. I had seen a Blender Guru tutorial which mentioned that for reducing render times, and had no idea it would have that effect on glass materials. Setting it to 0 fixed the issue. For now I have this setup, but it can use slightly more fresnel effect.[image]